# How to scroll in ScrollView by view in android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

i have 2 scrollView for displaying text and meaning of text.
In the first scrollview when i click on each words i can give position of meaning line(txt_word_meaning) in second scrollView,
my problem is in meaning scrollView when view is below of screen, scrollview could not scroll exactly on best position and it shows wrong position.

Here is my code :

```
final int totalHeight = scrollView_meaning.getChildAt(0).getHeight();

txt_word_meaning.getLocationInWindow(location);
int x = location[0];
y_position = location[1];
scrollView_meaning.post(new Runnable(){
     @Override
     public void run() {
            scrollView_meaning.scrollTo(60, y_position);
     }});
```

txt_word_meaning : meaning text created dynamically by unique id

[image]

Comment: You can use `NestedScrollView` for element in `ScrollView`

Comment: can you explain more?